# Doubts in Grep to display file name along with content

Tags: grep

Am using the following grep to match a particular pattern in `grep`.

```
grep xyz abc.txt
```

now while i run this command, if the pattern matched, am getting the line containing xyz

**Output:**

```
xyz is doing some work
```

Now if I want the file name also along with my output, what should I do

**Expected**

```
abc.txt:xyz is doing some work
```

I need this kind of output in `Solaris`. gnu had a option of -H in `grep`. But I need for `Solaris` flavour.

Answer (score 2):

If you don't have `-H` switch, use [awk](/questions/tagged/awk) instead :

```
awk '/pattern/{print FILENAME":"$0}'
```

Comment: Fixed typo in my response

Comment: that awk line cannot replace the grep one. but works for the example in question.

Comment: Thx, this worked.

Answer (score 1):

The filename is printed before each match when you search multiple files:

```
grep xyz abc.txt /dev/null
```